# Carousel not working, Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am trying a full-page landing image slider using bootstrap, but it's not working and in the console log, I got the error "Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined at ............"

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

I want the full page image slider to work as usual without any errors

Comment: i think bootstrap css and js not available. Please check your imports

Comment: You haven't posted any code that references `offsetWidth`.  You also concealed the culprit from us by eliding the error message:  _at ............_

Comment: @DasunManathunga bootstrap css and js is included

Comment: @Wyck the offsetWidth is defined in default bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.bundle.css

Comment: Can you update the snippet to use bootstrap and reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MageshBhaskaran  I have posted the working code. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="height: 100%">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="height: 100%">
          <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
          <div class="carousel-item active" style="height: 100%; background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
              <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
          <div class="carousel-item" style="height: 100%; background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
              <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
          <div class="carousel-item" style="height: 100%; background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
              <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```